# selecting an image from a list of images within same class

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make a carousel here.

here is my markup

```
<img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/1.jpg" >
<img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/2.jpg" >
<img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/3.jpg" >
<img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/4.jpg" >
```

Now i want to select the first image or the second image of the class without giving each image an id.
Please tell me how to do that.
I tried the `n-th child` but it didnt work.
thanks.

Comment: `$('.fullBg')[0]`?  What did you try and in what way did it not work?

Comment: As you will always have 1 active slide. You will probably always have one image with an extra class (for example `.active`). With jQuery you can then easily select the next img with the `next()` function and swap the active class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap that html in parent element like div. Then try:

```
$(parentselector).find("img:eq(1)");//for second image
$(parentselector).find("img:eq(0)");//for first image
```

Comment: Thanks anton. did not knew that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.fullBg').each(function() {
    // $(this) here will target each of your image with class fullBg 
});
```

If you want to target first image, you can use:

```
$('img.fullBg:eq(0)');
```

You can use **[:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** here, but you need to wrap your images inside a `div`, for example:

```
<div class="test">
    <img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/1.jpg" >
    <img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/2.jpg" >
    <img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/3.jpg" >
    <img  class="fullBg anim" src="img/bgs/4.jpg" >
</div>
```

then you can use:

```
$(".test img:nth-child(1)")
```

to target your first image or:

```
$(".test img:nth-child(2)")
```

to target your second image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select 1st,2nd etc..

```
$('img.fullBg:eq(1)'); //selects 2nd image
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq()` method with index starting from 0 , use negative value for select from end

```
$('img.fullBg').eq(0)//select first image
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/MW8VU/)

The above example select first image , for secong change `0` to `1`

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 1):

Just have your own css selector and give your own number instead of (2)

```
selector:nth-of-type(2)
```

[DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-of-type)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work (not tested), it removes the first from the list and adds it to the end:

```
setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slidediv > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slidediv');
        },  5000);
```

You'd need to wrap your  tags in a div called #slidediv

Answer (score 1):

For the first element:

```
$('.fullBg').eq(0);
```